# react-native message queue using expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm developing a mobile app which needs to produce and consume message over a message broker using react-native. As far as I search I could find just few libraries. One of them is react-native-rabbitmq but its using native modules which is not supported by Expo. My question is what is the best way of communicating with a message broker(Kafka, RabbitMQ, MQTT etc.) using Expo.Or I am open for any other solution instead of using message broker. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `ExpoKit`

Ejecting to `ExpoKit`

ExpoKit is an Objective-C and Java library that allows you to use the Expo platform and your existing Expo project as part of a larger standard native project -- one that you would normally create using Xcode, Android Studio, or `react-native init.`

If you created an `Expo project` and you want a way to add `custom native modules,` this guide will explain how to use `ExpoKit` for that purpose.
Normally, Expo apps are written in pure JS and never "drop down" to the `native iOS` or `Android layer`. This is core to the Expo philosophy and it's part of what makes Expo fast and powerful to use.
However, there are some cases where advanced developers need native capabilities outside of what Expo offers out-of-the-box. The most common situation is when a project requires a specific Native Module which is not supported by `React Native Core` or the `Expo SDK`.
In this case, Expo allows you to eject your pure-JS project from the `Expo` iOS/Android clients, providing you with native projects that can be opened and built with Xcode and Android Studio. Those projects will have dependencies on `ExpoKit`, so everything you already built will keep working as it did before.
We call this "ejecting" because you still depend on the `Expo SDK`, but your project no longer lives inside the standard `Expo client`. You control the `native projects`, including configuring and building them yourself.

[this link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/) is about Expokit

Comment: but with this way, I won't be able to use some expo features (sharing project with  QR code, expo build). right?

Comment: Project sharing is available as  `exp publish` and `expo build` is also possible. `android` is `expo start --android` or 'ios' is `expo start --ios.`